# Converting to Datetime gives wrong results. Python

Tags: python, matlab, datetime

I have a list of numbers that correspond to a particular time, but when I try to convert to datetime, it gives different results.

Here's my attempt for the first one

```
time = [733972.00069444, 733972.00138889, 733972.00208333]

dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(time[1])
```

and I get

```
Out[48]: datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 9, 6, 52, 52, 1389)
```

This is wrong because that number corresponds to

```
>> datestr(datenum(Date(1)))

ans =

    '18-Jul-2009 00:01:00'
```

Using Matlab. Any help on how to reconcile these two would be appreciated.

Comment: the python dt is correct https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: The matlab result is the one I'm after. The data I have corresponds to around 2009. I'm trying to see if it's possible to get the same result as that of matlab.

Comment: check the MATLAB [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html): I assume your numbers are "the whole and fractional number of days from a fixed, preset date (January 0, 0000) in the proleptic ISO calendar" - however, Python's `fromtimestamp()` expects POSIX seconds since the epoch.

Comment: @MrFuppes I don't think that's what I have, which is probably why I'm getting the results I have.

Comment: [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.posixtime.html) is what you need to feed into `fromtimestamp()` ...

Comment: I figured it out based on the docs you linked. Thanks